# Reading CSS properties applied to element using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style>
.mainclass{
width:900px;
color:red;
}
</style>
<div class="mainclass">
this is test text
</div>
```

Is there any way/possible in JavaScript that i can actually read all the css properties that are getting applied to the element ? like say el.style.color/width should actually return the style that is getting set/applied to this element.

I would like to  do this so that dom elements can be iterated to find out widths applied to elements and convert it to % for making responsive UI.

Comment: What's wrong with making it responsive *without* relying on JavaScript?

Comment: @cimmanon for responsive web design we convert px based layout to % based. Now there are so many new elements and only nice way i could think to get css widths set in code was with javascript iteration on dom... that was the whole purpose of it..

Comment: may be i will use ugly way to inspect each element and find widths now... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use jQuery, $(...).css() solves your problem.

```
var color = $('#yourid').css("color");
```

If you don't want jQuery you can use getComputedStyle on the element. See  http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/dhtmlcascade4.shtml for cross-browser solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this nice little framework:

- http://jquery.com/

It has a function for doing that:

- http://api.jquery.com/width/

Example:

```
$(function () {
    $("div").each(function (index, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        if ($el.width() > 300) {
            $el.css({width: "10%"});
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JvqAM/

Comment: Instead of just linking to a jQuery doc, I'd suggest you give an example.